# Why is taking address of function argument allowed in C?

Tags: c, function, rvalue

Suppose I write two functions:

```
int f() {
    return 1;
}

int g() {
    int* x = &f();
}
```

I can't compile this in C, because you "cannot take the address of an rvalue".  That makes sense, because the return value from `f` lives in a register.  (That is to say, it doesn't *have* an address to assign.)

On the other hand, I *can* compile this:

```
int h(int x) {
    int* y = &x;
    return 0;
}
```

Why?  The argument to `h` also lives in a register, so it should not have an address.  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function parameters are objects with automatic storage duration just like local variables inside of the function.

Section 6.9.1p8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following regarding function parameters:

> Each parameter has automatic storage duration; its identifier is an lvalue. The layout of the storage for parameters is unspecified.

And because function parameters are lvalues, their address can be taken.

Also, although not explicitly stated by the C standard, function parameters often reside on the stack just like local variables.

Comment: So I have two follow up questions:

1) My understanding of the C calling convention was that all arguments were passed in registers until they were exhausted, and only then were arguments pushed to the stack.

2) I thought pointers could only have the address of an object on the heap, but couldn't point to a memory area in the stack.

Are these both incorrect?

Comment: @broken.eggshell Calling convention is an implementation detail, and a pointer may point to *any* valid object regardless of where it resides.  There is no problem with `int x; int *y=&x`.

Comment: @broken.eggshell Even if they start out in registers, they usually don't stay in registers. They usually get spilled, and then you can take the address of where they got spilled to.

Comment: And just to be clear about one thing... Suppose int* y was declared globally instead of inside `h`, i.e. `int* y; void h(int x) { y = &x; }`.  After `h` returns, y is again a dangling pointer, correct?  `x` was created on the stack and `y` pointed to it for its short life, but now the stack is unwound and `y` just points to unused memory.

Comment: @broken.eggshell Yes, a pointer pointing to an object after its lifetime has ended has an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: @dbush: Re “a pointer may point to any valid object”: Bit-fields and objects declared with `register` are valid objects, but you cannot take their addresses.

Comment: @broken.eggshell: The so-called C calling convention is not part of the C standard and has no effect on the rules of the C standard. Regardless of whether the **values** of arguments are passed in registers or not, the C compiler (largely the compiler) is responsible for implementing parameters as required by the C standard, and that includes providing places for memory in them if necessary. If it has to copy the value of an argument from a register to a stack location to do that, then it does.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Re “They usually get spilled”: Where do your statistics on the frequency of argument spill come from?

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you .carry them across a function call, you have to put them somewhere nonvolatile. Sure, maybe it's a register, but not always. Instead of "usually" substitute "there's a good chance"